# I'm a nonresident alien who won and claimed a $50 giveaway through the internet before I realized this could give me a headache, please help

Tags: united-states, taxes, income-tax, irs, non-resident

This might be a silly question but:

I think I'm not obliged to file a tax report since my income from a U.S. source is only $50 (please correct me if I'm wrong). But what about paying the actual tax (it looks like the company didn't withheld the tax)? It seems there won't be a state tax because the company that gave me the $50 is in California but I'm not sure about federal taxes. Do I really have to mail a W-7 form to get a ITIN so that I can complete a Same-Day Taxpayer Worksheet so that I can finally request a International Wire Transfer to my bank just so that I can pay $5 federal tax (assuming the tax on $50 income is 10%)? Or does the very low value of my US income makes me exempt from paying any tax?

And considering that the $50 fell into my PayPal account on November 26, is it possible to give up the prize by transferring the money back to the same e-mail that gave it to me?

Btw, it seems my country doesn't have a tax treaty with the U.S., so I don't think paying the tax only in my home country would solve the question.

Thanks in advance! And sorry if my english is weird...

Comment: If you don't have to file a tax report that means you don't have to pay tax.

Comment: I would be more worried about a scam than taxes.  Most "giveaways" on the internet are scams not actual free money.

Comment: @DJClayworth You sure? That isn't the case in my country but if it is in the US then that is great, thx.

Comment: @dave Well, the money already showed up on my PayPal, it doesn't seem to be a scam.

Comment: @Lynn: Yes, because the rules for needing to file a US tax return are written in such a way that you would need to file if you would have nonzero tax.

Comment: The minimum income in the US before filing (and possibly paying) taxes was $12,400 last year for a single independent under the age of 65; lower for children, higher for other categories.  You're a long way from being of interest to the IRS.

Comment: @user4556274 That's absolutely not true for nonresident aliens - they don't get the standard deduction.  Not to say that they necessarily need to file a tax return, I'm not sure where that line runs, but there may are some minimal tax on $50, technically.

Comment: @DJClayworth: for US 'residents' (which actually includes citizens and LPRs located anywhere, and other aliens if defined as resident under the 'substantial presence test' which isn't always the same as actual residence)(!), you can never owe tax without being required to file. But for non-resident aliens like this Q, _most_ tax is withheld at source at a fixed or treaty rate, and if the withholding matched your tax liability you aren't required to file even though you did owe and pay tax.

Comment: @user102008: see previous. OP: if you did even trivial work, like solving a puzzle, this probably counts as 'services' income for tax treaty purposes and as long as you are not a US citizen or LPR and not resident under 7701, it is 'sourced' to your residence and not subject to US income tax. In any case IRS is certainly not going to pursue you over such a small amount; just sending you a notice (which is by far the cheapest thing they can do) would exceed their maximum gain.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085 No kind of work involved. No Tax was withheld at the source.